# Range slider filter with pure javascript by adding a function to my array.prototype

Tags: javascript, filter

I have a table populated with animals and need to filter them by population and i want to use a range slider to filter them without using jQuery, just plain javascript, already have 2 filters using array.prototype. Here is my html code:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Search by population</legend>
  <input id="populationSlider" class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="100" min="194" max="500000" onchange="updateSliderNumber('populationNumber', this.value);">
    <input id="populationNumber" type="number" value="100" min="194" max="500000" onchange="updateSliderNumber('populationSlider', this.value);">
  <span class="range-slider__value"></span>
</fieldset>
```

and here is my sript:

```
(function(document) {

    var AnimalFilter = (function(Arr) {

        var _input;
    var _select;

        function _onInputEvent(e) {
            _input = e.target;
            var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
            Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
                Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                    Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
                });
            });
        }

        function _onSelectEvent(e) {
            _select = e.target;
            var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_select.getAttribute('data-table'));
            Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
                Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                    Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filterSelect);
                });
            });
        }

        function _filter(row) {

            var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
            row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';

        }

        function _filterSelect(row) {

            var text_select = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val_select = _select.options[_select.selectedIndex].value.toLowerCase();
            row.style.display = text_select.indexOf(val_select) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';

        }

        return {
            init: function() {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('table-filter');
                var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('select-table-filter');
                Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                    input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
                });
                Arr.forEach.call(selects, function(select) {
         select.onchange  = _onSelectEvent;
                });
            }
        };
    })(Array.prototype);

    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            AnimalFilter.init();
        }

    });


})(document);

// Range-slider
function updateSliderNumber(id, value){
    document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
```

Ant suggestions?Do i need to call another function, or extend my prototype.array? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with `Array.prototype`. And no, you should not extend that.

Comment: What does not work as expected? (hint: you apply either the one filter or the other, but not both)